# IDE - show there exist a solution for $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=5e^{x-2y}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

we have not learned PDE or something like that, but our professor decided we need to learn it for the first time at Fourier analysis course.
Anyway, they want us to guess a solution
The clue is: $u(x,y)=e^{ax+by}$ and find $a,b$.
Which I really have no clue, since we have not learned it.

Please tell me how do I proceed when having to do such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $u_{xx} = a^2u$ and $u_{yy} = b^2u$. Substituting this into your PDE gives $(a^2 + b^2)e^{ax + by} = 5e^{x - 2y}$. You can compare both sides now to find $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Hi, wait what did you do?
Why $u_{xx}=a^2u$ and the same with $u_{yy}$? As said, we have not learned it :\

Comment: @LearningToCode If $u(x, y) = e^{a x + b y}$, then its second partial derivative with respect to $x$, $u_{xx}$ is $u_{x x}(x, y) = a^2 e^{a x + b y} = a^2 u(x, y)$.

Comment: oh I see!! Thanks!!

Comment: in a few minutes when I will be able, I will accept the answer :)
Thank you very much

Comment: By the way, just for curiosity, if I wasnt given the guess function, is there a way to solve it? or it is too high class for my level

Comment: @LearningToCode It would be natural to guess the solution to be $e^{ax + by}$, since you have the Poisson equation $\Delta u = u_{xx} + u_{yy} = f(x, y)$ and $f(x, y)$ is an exponential function.

Comment: Oh, that is a first time for me hearing it.
@CheeHan Thanks!